# UV Unwrap not working in Blender 2.9x

Tags: modeling, uv

As a newbie in Blender, (I'm a lightwave and Modo 3d user) I'm probably just beginning posting questions here, I hope I won't bother you too much.
So, I'm trying to unwrap some sort of a low poly dinosaur, I followed some tutorials but It doesn't work for me.  See the video:

https://youtu.be/2YmFlE3n9OQ

Thank you!

Comment: I can't see in your videos if you mark your seams. watch thiis https://youtu.be/Y7M-B6xnaEM?t=199 and see if that helps, if not, you could share your blend file to take a look at it

Comment: Hello :). You're in Image Editor - you need to use the UV editor to see your UV map :).

Answer (score 2):

You are currently in **Image editor** which is kinda similar to uv editor but isn't the same thing see on the top below title bar you see some **workspaces** , like **layout** , **modelling** , there is one workspace known as **uv editing** , there if you have a look at your uv's , you will realize that they are already there but you were looking for them somewhere else

Comment: Oh, no way!!! That's the image editor, ok. Opening the UV layout, I didn't expect to get an image grid instead of the uv grid by default, thank you guys!

Comment: you can click the tick mark below the question voting to declare this awnsere as corrects to help people in future to anticipate what worked for you